# Mock static functions called in the main function that is being tested

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to mock some functions within a function I am testing.

I have a class that has several static private functions being called from the so-called `mainFunction`. I want to particularly test the result of `MyClass.functionD` (called by `mainFunction`, which is a private method), therefore, I would like to mock `MyClass.functionA`, `MyClass.functionB` and `MyClass.functionC` to return a default result so that my test can focus on the result of `MyClass.fucntionD`.

```
export default class MyClass {

   static mainFunction(paramA: string, paramB: number): boolean {

        if (MyClass.functionA(paramA, paramB)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!MyClass.functionB(paramA, paramB)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (MyClass.functionC(paramA, paramB)) {
            return false;
        }

        // I need to focus on the result of this function (i.e. private) for my test
        if (MyClass.functionD(paramA)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
   }

}
```

So far, I have tried jest `spyOn` and some default mock function but I am just lost and cannot proceed as I am really new to typescript / Javascript. Any hint/reference related to how I should proceed would be enough for me. :) Thanks.

Comment: It may be better to treat mainFunction as a single unit and not take private methods into account at all. This is not always so, but if you can't justify mocking then they probably shouldn't be mocked at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript public/private keywords only apply to the way TypeScript checks your code - they don't have any effect on the JavaScript output. So you can access these private methods via [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like `MyClass['fucntionA']`, that will ignore the type check of TSC. Then you can use `jest.spyOn` to mock these private methods.

Here is my test strategy for your case:

`MyClass.ts`:

```
export default class MyClass {
  static mainFunction(paramA: string, paramB: number): boolean {
    if (MyClass.fucntionA(paramA, paramB)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!MyClass.fucntionB(paramA, paramB)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (MyClass.fucntionC(paramA, paramB)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (MyClass.fucntionD(paramA)) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  private static fucntionA(a, b) {
    return true;
  }

  private static fucntionB(a, b) {
    return false;
  }

  private static fucntionC(a, b) {
    return true;
  }
  private static fucntionD(a) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

`MyClass.test.ts`:

```
import MyClass from './MyClass';

describe('65376946', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    const fucntionASpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass as any, 'fucntionA').mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    const fucntionBSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass as any, 'fucntionB').mockReturnValueOnce(true);
    const fucntionCSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass as any, 'fucntionC').mockReturnValueOnce(false);
    const fucntionDSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass as any, 'fucntionD').mockReturnValueOnce(true);

    const actual = MyClass.mainFunction('a', 1);
    expect(actual).toBeFalsy();
    expect(fucntionASpy).toBeCalledWith('a', 1);
    expect(fucntionBSpy).toBeCalledWith('a', 1);
    expect(fucntionCSpy).toBeCalledWith('a', 1);
    expect(fucntionDSpy).toBeCalledWith('a');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
PASS  examples/65376946/MyClass.test.ts
  65376946
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   42.86 |       50 |      20 |   42.86 |                   
 MyClass.ts |   42.86 |       50 |      20 |   42.86 | 4,8,12,19-34      
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.168 s
```

Comment: Perfect! I have a question though. Could you please explain the purpose of using `toBeCalledWith`? Can we just ignore it as we are already passing params to mainFunction that would eventually be used in child functions (In this case, they are mocked anyways)?

Comment: @ihaider To assert that the mocked functions to be called with expected parameters. In other words, the purpose is to assert that your code execution path is correct. Each test case should test one code execution path